# Validate sqlachemy session

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy to store values in my database. I want to write test cases that can validate a session.

The code for getting a session object:

```
def get_session():
    Base = declarative_base()
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://testdb:hello@localhost/mydatabase')
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DBSession()
    return session
```

The problem is that even if I put a wrong database name, the above code still works. When I try to commit to database, then it throws an error(OperationalError).

How can I validate my session during its creation?

Comment: Can you tell us what you're attempting to gain by doing so? Suppose you validate and then the session drops for some reason (meaning you think you're doing something valid when you're not)? Suppose you validate and then do nothing to use the database once you've discovered it's there (meaning you've probably made an expensive call to the db)? It is structured this way to 'lazily' respond only when you access the db.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://testdb:hello@localhost/wrongdbname')

Suppose, this 'wrongdbname' does not exists. When I create a session, it should throw some error. But it doesn't. When I try to enter values in tables, it throws OperationalError because the 'wrongdbname' does not exists.

Comment: Are you dynamically calling a database? It's generally considered 'not recommended' to make a call to the db just to ensure it's there. This is something that would be found in testing: no query will work if the db isn't configured properly. By executing code to ensure it is, you will be doing so on every call into that code. If this is a web application that is every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def validate(session):
    try:
        # Try to get the underlying session connection, If you can get it, its up
        connection = session.connection()
        return True
    except:
        return False
```